# How to keep refetching (refetch) `useQuery` even after the component unmounts?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-query, tanstackreact-query

I am using `useQuery` and its `refetch` option to download a file in the frontend. The download process is of two steps, and I am displaying the below notifications to the users:

1. Download process is started, the file will automatically download once the file is ready
2. The download has now been completed

Both these notifications are displayed to the user, and the idea is to allow the user to navigate anywhere in the application while the download is being processed.

There are two APIs:

1. API 1 - used for displaying the first notification. I use `refetch` option with this to check if the download is ready.
2. API 2 - used for downloading the file once the API returns "Ready for download" status

For this, I have created a custom `hook` where I call the `useQuery` for each API

**Custom hook structure:**

```
export const useFileDownload = () => {

 const [fileReady, setFileReady] = useState(false);

 const { isError, isLoading, mutate } = useDownloadBegin({ //this uses useQuery with refetch option
    onSuccess: (data) => {
      setFileReady(true);
    }
 });

 const { isError, isLoading, mutate } = useDownloadFile({ //this downloads file using useQuery
    enabled: fileReady;
    . . .
 });


}
```

**My Component:**

```
<DownloadModal {props} />
```

**Download Modal:**

```
export const DownloadModal = ({...props}) => {
   const { isDownloading } = useFileDownload();
   
   return(
    <>Download Modal</>
   )
  

}
```

**What is the issue?**

Once I navigate to another page, API 1 stops getting executed, and I am never able to download the file using API 2. It works absolutely fine if I stay on the same page.

I believe, the hook does not get executed once I go to another page, as the component gets unmounted.

How do I make sure that hook gets executed asynchronously even when navigated away from the component?

**What have I tried?**

I explored different options available in [tanstack useQuery](https://tanstack.com/query/v4/docs/react/reference/useQuery) like `refetchIntervalInBackground`.

Also, since I do not have a `store` in my application, I am trying to work around `context` to see if I can use it for my purpose. But, I am still not sure about it.

Comment: I'ld say: you're feature shouldn't be scoped for `DownloadModal` component, b/c you expect it to work even outside of it. Therefore, I'ld move the logic up to an overarching component which doesn't get unmounted, e.g. `App` or the alike.

Comment: I also think about using `context`, so you can just take a try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right track. You need a Context Provider at the top of your app, such that every page the user might visit following the download process initiating will be within the provider's context, e.g.

```
<DownloadProvider>
  <Page1 />
  <Page2>
    <Page2a />
    <Page2b />
  </Page2>
  <Page3 />
</DownloadProvider>
```

You can make use of your existing `useFileDownload` hook in the provider. You don't say what initiates the download process, so I'm guessing it's a button click or similar, in which case your `useFileDownload` hook will need to return  the ability for the hook to know it can begin the process, e.g. (using an `enableDownload` state property as demonstrated here):

**Custom hook**

```
export const useFileDownload = () => {

  const [enableDownload, setEnableDownload] = useState(false);    
  const [fileReady, setFileReady] = useState(false);

  const {
    isError,
    isLoading,
    mutate
  } = useDownloadBegin({ //this uses useQuery with refetch option
    enabled: enableDownload,
    onSuccess: (data) => {
      setFileReady(true);
    }
  });

  const {
    isError,
    isLoading,
    mutate
  } = useDownloadFile({ //this downloads file using useQuery
    enabled: fileReady;
    ...
  });

  return {
    setEnableDownload
  };
}
```

The idea being that whatever UI initiates the download process can just call `setEnableDownload(true)`.

Your context provider will make use of this hook, this will make `setEnableDownload` available to any descendant component that needs to use it:

**download-provider.jsx**

```
const DownloadContext = createContext({});

const DownloadProvider = ({ children}) => {
  const { setEnableDownload }  = useFileDownload();

  const contextValues = { setEnableDownload };

  return (
    <DownloadContext.Provider value={contextValues}>
      {children}
    </DownloadContext.Provider>
  );
};

export default DownloadProvider;
export { DownloadContext };
```

You can then add your context provider to the top of your page hierarchy:

```
import DownloadProvider from './download-provider.jsx';

...

    return (
      <DownloadProvider>
        <...Top level page component...>
      </DownloadProvider>
    );

...
```

And, finally, in the component that needs to initiate the download, you can use the provided `setEnableDownload` method:

```
import { DownloadContext } from '../../download-provider.jsx';

...

  const { setEnableDownload }  = useContext(DownloadContext);

...
```

and call it as appropriate to initiate the download process, and because the hook is being used by a provider at the top of your component tree, it will continue operating regardless of the user navigating around the app.